# Why do variables in my struct appear as const?

Tags: c++

So I have a struct to make storing and comparing of x y coordinates easier.

I'm trying to get two sets of coordinates, so four numbers in total, as input from the user and stored in two 'Card_position' structs but I can't seem to get it to work from within the for loop.

On the for loop line it gives me an error: binding value of type 'const int' to reference to type 'int' drops 'const' qualifier
even though nothing has a const qualifier.

My solution was to just do it without the loop but I would like to know the real solution.
Here's a snippet of where the error is coming from.

```
    Card_position guess1{0, 0};
    Card_position guess2{0, 0};

    while (true)
    {
        cout << player.get_name() << ": " << INPUT_CARDS;
        string input = "";

        for (int& guess : {guess1.x, guess1.y, guess2.x, guess2.y} )
        {
            cin >> input;
            if(input == "q")
                return 1;
            guess = stoi_with_check(input);
        }
```

I tried without the reference but then it just won't save the values into the structs. Any solutions?

here is the struct definition:

```
struct Card_position
{
    int x;
    int y;

    bool operator ==(Card_position& other)
    {
        return (this->x == other.x) && (this->y == other.y);
    }

    bool operator <(Card_position& minimum)
    {
        return (this->x < minimum.x) || (this->y < minimum.y);
    }

    bool operator >(Card_position& max)
    {
        return (this->x > max.x) || (this->y > max.y);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the initializer list (`{guess1.x, guess1.y, guess2.x, guess2.y}`) that stores those ints internally as const, and then the `int &` cannot bind to that value. You can get around this by using an [`std::reference_wrapper'](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper):

```
for (auto guess : {std::ref(guess1.x), std::ref(guess1.y), std::ref(guess2.x), std::ref(guess2.y)} )
{
    cin >> input;
    if(input == "q")
        return 1;
    guess = stoi_with_check(input);
}
```

The `guess` is then intialized by a copy of that wrapper, that can be manipulated and will be able to edit the value it points to. (Alternatively, you can use pointers like this:

```
for (int* guess : {&guess1.x, &guess1.y, &guess2.x, &guess2.y} )
{
    cin >> input;
    if(input == "q")
        return 1;
    *guess = stoi_with_check(input);
}
```

Comment: This is how I solved it. Thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 2):

Because an initializer list [gives a const iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/begin).

This is creating an initializer list:

```
{guess1.x, guess1.y, guess2.x, guess2.y}
```

I’m not really sure what the point of this construction is anyways because assigning to these values makes little sense, since you can't retrieve them after the for loop.

Maybe you are looking for something like this?

```
std::vector<int> v{guess1.x, guess1.y, guess2.x, guess2.y};
for (int& guess : v)
{ // ...
```

Comment: The intention is to bind references to the members of the guess objects. Then changing them will change the guess objects and they live outside of the loop. Your proposed solution will make copies of those members.